# Set the working directory when starting a process with boost

Tags: c++, boost

I am looking for a way to specify the working directory when starting a process with `boost::process::system` or `boost::process::child`. In the docs https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html are some useful examples, but nothing on the subject of my interest.

The `child` constructor looks like this:

```
template<typename ...Args>
child::child(Args&&...args)
```

and I haven't found complete documentation covering what the `Args` might be, only some incomplete  examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <boost/process/start_dir.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::process;

int result = bp::system("/usr/bin/g++", "main.cpp", bp::start_dir("/home/user"));

bp::child c(bp::search_path("g++"), "main.cpp", bp::start_dir("/home/user"));
c.wait();
```

See [boost::process::start_dir](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost/process/start_dir.html) and the complete [Reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/process/reference.html).

Args are program name, program args and other process properties from the Reference.

Comment: Cool, thanks! `start_dir` did the trick. As for the link to the Reference, I can't find there a complete list of what might be params of `bp::child`